# How to display a spinner loader in video when it buffering?

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I create a video tag by JavaScript and I play the video to the canvas element I have in my document.

```
var v = document.createElement('video');
```

I want to know when the video is buffering.

So I try to simulate a slow video connect using devtools:

[image]

And `addEventListener` to waiting event to the video element- but it not fire. Also I try to do it with videojs and listen to events, but "waiting" doesn't fire ither.

What can I do?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var v = document.createElement('video');
  v.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  v.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/dwaquopnm/video/upload/v1582007937/blink2013_itacxp.mp4";

 var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var back = document.createElement('canvas');
 var backcontext = back.getContext('2d');
 
 var cw,ch;
  
  console.log({ v });
 
 v.addEventListener('play', function(){
  cw = 200;
  ch = 200;
  canvas.width = cw;
  canvas.height = ch;
  back.width = cw;
  back.height = ch;
  draw(v,context,backcontext,cw,ch);
 },false);
  
  var vd  = videojs(v);
  
  console.log({ vd });
  
  vd.on('play', function() {
    console.log('play!!');
  });
  
  vd.on('waiting', function() {
    console.log('waiting3!!');
  });
  
  vd.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log('loadedmetadata!!');
  });
  
 
  var btn = document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', function() {
    v.play();
  });
    
},false);

function draw(v,c,bc,w,h) {
  
 if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
 // First, draw it into the backing canvas
 bc.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
 // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
 var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,w,h);

 // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
 c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
 // Start over!
 setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,bc,w,h);
}
```

```html
  <button id="clicker">click</button>
  <canvas id="c" ></canvas> 
  
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
```